# Help me find a source for glossing "sefer" (in Shabbat 14a) as "Torah, Nevi'im, and Ketuvim"

Tags: tanach, rashi, sefer-torah, maseches-shabbos, maseches-yadayim

In *Shabbat* 14a we find a discussion about the Rabbinic enactment that a book (*sefer*) renders one's hands unclean (which is itself discussed in the Mishnah *Yadayim* 3:5).  Long ago I found a source (which I wrote down) that on 14a Rashi glosses "*sefer*" as referring to "all *kitvei ha-kodesh* -- *Torah, Nevi'im* and *Ketuvim*".  But I just checked that *daf* and I don't see anything like that in the Rashi, which means I must have gotten that gloss from somewhere else (or it is there and I am just not seeing it for some reason).

Can anybody help me track down the source for that gloss?

To be clear, I am aware that there are extensive discussions elsewhere about the status of *individual* books (Esther, Kohelet, Shir ha-Shirim) and whether or not they are *m'tamei et hayadayim*.  I am not looking for that.

Comment: Well if you just want a source that Rashi explains that sfarim refers to all kisvei kodesh see Rashi to Megillah 8b (IIRC). Yup...Rashi to the Mishnah.

Comment: Specifically, I think you are looking for Rashi on [*M'gilla* 7a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=7&format=text): אינה מטמאה את הידים. כשאר ספרים דאמר ביציאות השבת (דף יד.) שגזרו עליהן לטמא את הידים.

Comment: I'm looking in particular for a clear statement that "kitvei kodesh" means "Torah, Nevi'im, and Ketuvim."  (As opposed to "only Torah" or "any written text with God's name on it").

Comment: @mweiss That's the implied meaning when Rashi uses the expression "כשאר ספרים". *S'farim* in that context means books of Tanach.

Comment: @Fred I don't disagree that is the implied meaning, I am just looking for a place where he states it explicitly.

Comment: @mweiss Well, as mevaqesh pointed out, Rashi defines ספרים that way explicitly on 8b, but it is in a different context.

Comment: @Fred, let me see if I have the logic right: On 8b, we learn that *s'farim* can be written in any language, and Rashi explains that in that context "*s'farim*" means *Torah, Nevi'im, Ketuvim*. On 7a Rashi tells us that *s'farim* defile the hands. So may we infer that the word means the same thing in that context? If so, that would seem to imply that even in another language they defile the hands. That can't be right, can it?

Comment: @mweiss That's a good question. Maybe *s'farim* written in יוונית do in fact defile hands?

Comment: @Fred Actually, they might. The defilement was an entirely Rabbinic enactment to ensure that people treated the s'farim with care and respect. If the s'farim were usable (and it seems like even in other languages they were), then no distinction would be made between them. Based on OP's response, perhaps it's ***even more imperative*** to treat foreign language s'farim with respect, as people are more prone to treating them in a degenerate manner. There are other halachos like this, but they currently elude me (perhaps harchakos for niddah?)...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Maybe, but see the mishna (*Yadayim* 4:5, codified by the Rambam in [*Hil. Avos HaTum'a* 9:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=60&perek=9&halocha=7)), which seems to say that it has to be written in *k'sav Ashuris* in order to defile hands: "תרגום שכתבו עברית ועברית שכתבו תרגום וכתב עברי, אינו מטמא את הידיים. לעולם אינו מטמא עד שיכתבנו אשורית על העור ובדיו". Though perhaps you could argue that this limitation applies only to defiling hands for תרומה, whereas maybe even יוונית could defile hands for קודש.

Comment: @Fred Beautiful find! Looks like I was wrong about that. Sheesh. I missed that mishnah in yadayim? I need to pay attention more during my chazarah. This definitely seems to define the shiur of a sefer as being in ashuris, which would render other langages a moot point (unless they're written in ashuris like yiddish?) Also, we just covered in (tomorrow's) daf shiur that Rashi identifies "s'farim" as being Tanach.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Then perhaps you could post that Rashi as an answer here?

Comment: I'm currently listening to it again, trying to pick it out...

Comment: Sefer she'aynah mugah - rashi says it's Tanach. Rambam says it's specifically a sefer torah. Rosh said this is in respect to sources from which we pasken, which in those days didn't include written gemara and mishnayos. In our times, the Rosh holds that anything we pasken from can't be written wrong as it might lead to improper halachic actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a רש"י in שבת on [Daf :י"ג](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00879.html#HtmpReportNum0023_L2) that says:

> **והספר**. כל כתבי הקודש **תורה נביאים וכתובים** פוסלין תרומה במגען

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Apparently I was off by one page (I thought it was on 14a).  Many thanks!